# For electronic music production, are there any differences between using small synths vs big synths?

Tags: synthesizer, ableton-live, production, electronic-music, fl-studio

This is a newbie question by someone who is just learning to play piano.

On YouTube there are some talented musicians that play and remake famous electronic music riffs and tunes.

One group uses very small devices such as AKAI MK3 together with software like FL Studio or Ableton.

Another group uses big, expensive synths such as Yamaha Tyros with seemingly no DAW software.

What are pros and cons of each of these two methods?

Also for production, which method do DJs such as Tiesto, ATB, Ferry Corsten, or younger well-known DJs use to produce their songs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the MK3 or the Tyros are actually making the sounds!     The MP3 is purely a controller keyboard, it doesn't HAVE any sounds.  The Tyros is a high-end 'home keyboard' with lots of neat auto-accompaniment features, but it's not strong on 'classic synth' programmability.     It's all done in a DAW.  Don't worry about what they look like they're playing on a promotional video!

Comment: So for a newbie with limited budget, I wouldn't lose much if I go with MK3 or other devices such as Roilo Blocks, right? And it is not only budget that it is a factor here, I don't have room for a massive synth (I have a small noob-level keyboard though).

Comment: Your 'massive synth' will be software instruments in your DAW.  If you have keyboard skills, you will probably find it rewarding to sometimes 'play' them from a keyboard - as well as the notes, pitch and modulation wheels will also come in useful.   But I think much of today's music is produced without any use of a music keyboard at all!

Comment: So to conclude, I will do fine with something like MK3 + FL Studio or Ableton, right?